# Android Studio Translations Editor - Find usage

Tags: android, android-studio, localization, translation

Is there any way or shortcut that one can find usage (ALT-F7) of a key directly from Android Studio Translation Editor?

Answer (score 2):

I can't see that there's a way to do that directly, unfortunately. The best option seems to be to highlight a cell corresponding to an existing string for the desired key, jump to the declaration (from the right click menu) of that string,

[image: Android Studio screenshot showing string value right click menu options]

and find usages from there using the normal shortcut :/